# Unable to select database from PopSQL

Tags: mysql, popsql

I am trying to modify mySQL database with PopSQL. I put the following in the connection and it does not give and error. However, I can not select the databases I created. I am able to see the databases in mySQL workbench.
What should I do to be able to modify this database in popSQL?

```
[connect to local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69FxT.png)
[No databases as options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufTTC.png)
[saf is the database that I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkBj0.png)
```